# Dell XPS13 9310 boot issues after latest security updates/Ubuntu Base - 20.04.1

Tags: boot, updates, dell, intel-graphics, intel

I have been keeping up to date on security updates on my new (2 month old) XPS13 Developer addition. This morning there were a variety of updates which I applied.  During the next re-boot the splash screen came up and was filled with 'garbage' (kind of like the matrix screen saver!) and would not continue the boot process. I ended up booting into the advanced menu and re-loaded the OS from the rescue partition. I tried various updates individually (many times!)and found that the kernel updates (am now on 5.6.0-1033-oem) was not the issue nor were any of the application updates. The issue happens when performing the 'Security Updates - Ubuntu Base' files. There are a lot of these files and it is painful to have to start over again after each failed attempt. Before I continue down this road does anyone have a better suggestion? Any ideas what might be happening?  Maybe an Intel chipset update since the chipset is so new??   Anyone else dealing with this?

Comment: I have the same issue, and couldn't find the solution yet.
Tried adding the grub boot parameters like: `i915.enable_fbc=1` with and without `i915.enable_psr=0`, they change anything. Currently loading the previous kernel lets me into the system. Please share the solution, if you find it.

Comment: They just came out with a new update, and the system boots again.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm tied up until this weekend but will try out the update and report the results as soon as I can.  Did the update show up in the Software Updater application?  Do you happen to know the file name?  Yesterday I cross posted into reddit and was told by u/alexmurray that the problem was addressed: [link](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-4628-2)   ..  Was wondering if this was the same update you saw Kostanos?  Thanks for your report - appreciate the quick response from you and u/alexmurray.  :)

Comment: As of this morning (11/12/20) -> I looked in the Software Updater and the updated file is there.  If I get a chance today I'll apply the update and report back.  Version 3.20201110.0ubuntu0.20.04.2: 

  * SECURITY REGRESSION: Some CPUs in the Tiger Lake family sig=0x806c1
    fail to boot (LP: #1903883)
    - remove 06-8c-01/0x000806c1 microcode

Comment: The problem was resolved for my situation (thanks u/alexmurray). If you are having problems booting a Tiger Lake laptop after the update on Tuesday 11/10/20 - try https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-4628-2